# Set height to all divs with a specific class using pure js

Tags: javascript, class, height

Hi I'm trying to do something which I don't think should be that hard in javascript but I can't get it to work. I have a number of `div`s with the class `nav-img`, which have a width of 20%. I want the `div`s to always have the same aspect ratio, no matter the size of the window. The height should be width/1.35. Here is what I tried :

```
var vNavimg = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-img");
var vNavWidth = window.getComputedStyle(vNavimg).width;
window.onload = setHeight;

function setHeight() {
    vNavimg.style.height = vNavWidth/1.35+"px";
}
```

Comment: Sound like a job for CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close, the method **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)** return an array of the objects who have the given class as argument, you should loop through them and assign the new height  :

```
var vNavimg = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-img");

for(var i=0;i<vNavimg.length;i++){
    vNavimg[i].style.height = vNavWidth/1.35+"px";
}
```

Or using the function `setHeight()` :

```
var vNavimg = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-img");

for(var i=0;i<vNavimg.length;i++){
    setHeight(vNavimg[i]);
}

function setHeight(div) {
    div.style.height = vNavWidth/1.35+"px";
}
```

Hope this helps.